# Удалить метку [else]?

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Метка [else](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/else) почти всегда используется вместе с [if](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if).  И если
первую ещё как-то можно понять (детали работы условных команд в разных
языках), то вторая кажется мне совершенно лишней.  Посему, предлагаю
удалить.

Comment: На enSO это [синоним](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/if-statement/synonyms) к [tag:if-statement].

Comment: python: `try-except-else`, `for-else`.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica  Это скорее к [tag:try] и [tag:for] соответственно.

Comment: @insolor По-моему так было прикольно. Зачем удалять?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica 1 - это не ваш вопрос. Я считаю, что некорректно добавлять какие-либо "приколы" в чужие сообщения. 2 - ваша правка ухудшает читаемость. В первую очередь должно быть информативно и читаемо, а потом уже "прикольно". Да и "прикол" так себе.

Comment: @insolor Ладно, правы. ;)

Answer (score 19):

Удалить эту метку  ( [else](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/else) ) вовсе.

Comment: Удалять метки бессмысленно. Они появляются потом всё равно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ менять на другую, когда появится?

Comment: На какую другую? Синонимнуть и забыть о ней.

Comment: Мусор надо выбрасывать, даже если он потом появляется всё равно

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Можно занести метку в черный список. Тогда ее нельзя будет добавлять в вопросы. Если не ошибаюсь, то в таком списке метка `ошибка`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov такое только Николай может сделать. Насколько я помню, модераторы этот список редактировать не могут.

Comment: @4per Зачем этот сизифов труд, если можно синонимизировать? Появляется метка не просто так как мусор, а в определенном контексте. Поэтому красивые слова про мусор можно тоже смело выкинуть. Как мусор.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik  Сколько обычно идёт голосование?

Comment: @Ainar-G да уже достаточно, думаю. Надо теперь только это реализовать. Напомните в субботу, посмотрю)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik  С небольшим опозданием, напоминаю.

Comment: @Ainar-G да, я Николаю передал. Разработчики должны добавить в ЧС)

Answer (score 12):

Сделать синонимом к [if](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if) как и на enSO.

Comment: А `IF` потом тоже удалить ;-)